# Завершение процесса .NET

Tags: c#, google-chrome, процесс, .net

Всем доброго времени суток. Задача: я запускаю процесс (браузер chrome c заданным url), после нескольких операций мне нужно закрыть эту же страничку. Запускаю с помощью

```
var proc = Process.Start(..);
```

и завершаю с помощью, `proc.Kill();` во всех браузерах работает сносно, в хроме же выкидывает ошибку, что такой процесс не существует. Как быть? Всем заранее спасибо.

P.S js не предлагать, так как нужно именно нативно закрыть страницу. Так же открыв диспетчер задач, выяснил, что хром плодит свои процессы, отдельно плагины отдельно страницы, получается мне нужно как-то выловить мою страничку и корректно завершить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, вы сами почти ответили на свой вопрос - посмотреть PID нужного вам процесса можно в вкладке `Viev Background Pages -> rbt-click -> Process PID` поставить галочку. Единственное, когда я попробовал через терминал убить процесс, то на странице появился "Мертвый Джим", предпологаю, что нужно убивать и остальные процессы. В общем смотрите в эту сторону.

Comment: ну этот вариант грубоват, где то на steckoverflow человек написал, что можно запустить хром с url, и с ним положить ключ в title, потом когда все выполнилось найти страничку по этому ключу и убить процесс, просто теперь не могу найти этот пост, и нечего похожего не могу найти.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема с хромом в том, что он активно создаёт и удаляет дочерние процессы, и если вы запускаете хром, когда он уже запущен, он прицепится к существующему, а этот процесс исчезнет.

Варианты решения:

1. Убивать все процессы хрома по имени
2. Запустить хром с параметром `--user-data-dir=`, что создаст отдельный профиль для хрома и будет гарантировать, что он не прицепится к существующему. Закрывать хром через `proc.CloseMainWindow()` (позволит ему гарантированно добить своих детишек).